# Angular: Change host style if host is clickable

Tags: angular, sass

Is there a way to change the style of the host if the component has a `(click)="..."` property on it?

Something like this:

`app.component.html`

```html
<my-example (click)="..."></my-component>
```

`my-example.component.scss`

```css
:host {
 cursor: default;
}


/* If element has (click) attribute use this style */
:host-context([(click)]) {
 cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by using the `@HostBinding` decorator.

In your .ts file, you need to bind some property to the `style.cursor` attribute and toggle it when you want.

Something like this:

```
  @HostBinding('style.cursor') styleCursor: 'default' | 'pointer' = 'default';
    
  showAlert(event) {
     this.styleCursor = this.styleCursor === 'default' ? 'pointer' : 'default';
     ....
  }
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. In the example above I wanted to illustrate that the click is happening directly on the host from outside.  The component must then somehow know that (click) has been added to the element tag. That's what I was going for.